# How to reset an Autonumber field depending on another field?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

it's another question from an Access newbie here.

I have created a table that registers each interaction a person has with a client where one can find, amongst others, two fields - one representing each client uniquely and one for the number of the interaction with said client.

Is it possible for this number of interaction to be set as an Autonumber that resets everytime the record refers to a new client, given its unique ID?

Kind regards,

Laisinco

Comment: In almost all databases, you should need to do this using a trigger.

Comment: If you can calculate this value from other data, normal guidance would be to not store it at all, simply calculate it whenever it's required.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have found the correspondent to triggers in Access through Before & After Events, though I'm not sure how to write things in a way that if the client's ID is new in this table, the [#Interaction] field should be populated with 1; and if the client's ID is not new, then the same field should be populated with the maximum number already present + 1. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Minty The client's ID is stored in another tabled with some relevant information about each client (being the PK there). This table is supposed to track the interactions with the client (Client's ID as FK here) and the number of times they have occurred would be helpful to help keep track of the progress.

Comment: In that case a simple query ClientID, Count(ClientID) as Interactions FROM YourTable Group By ClientID  will give you list of all client ID's and the number of interactions. Link that with an left join to your normal forms recordsource and you can display it any time you want. No triggers / trying to remember to update records on changes made anywhere etc etc.

Comment: Autonumber will give you here very little benefit and the risk of data corruption if you insert rows to the table from somewhere else and no, no triggers in Access

Comment: @Minty That seems like a very good idea, I'm just not understanding the part where you say "display it". Do you mean that it will actually appear in the Interactions control in the form or appear as a table in split view where the user can then check how many interactions there have been so far and manually fill the number of a new interaction accordingly?

Comment: You can use it wherever you want, it's difficult to say without seeing your form design, or what the purpose of the form is.

Comment: How are you adding records to this table? Is the form bound or are you inserting by use of a query?